# How to iterate over a dictionary and modify values in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python dictionary, and I want to iterate over its key-value pairs and modify the values based on a certain condition. Here is an example dictionary:

```py
my_dict = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if value < 25:
        value = value * 2  # This doesn't seem to modify the original dictionary
```

Comment: And what exactly does this have to do with OpenCV? Please, don't abuse tags.

Answer (score 3):

You can reference the original dictionary in your code to edit the value for the given key -

```
my_dict = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if value < 25:
        my_dict[key] = value * 2
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
my_dict.update({k : v*2 for k,v in my_dict.items() if v > 25})
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing `value = value * 2`, you're just creating a NEW variable called `value`, and therefore redefining what you had previously stored in that variable. Note that in any case, the `value` variable contains the value of `my_dict[key]`, but it's not a reference to the original object itself.

What you need to do instead, is accessing the dictionary using the key of that iteration to assign it to a new value (which in your case, it will be the double of the previous amount):

```py
my_dict = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if value < 25:
        my_dict[key] = value * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension as well like the following code.

```py
my_dict = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}
my_dict = {key: value * 2 if value < 25 else value for key, value in my_dict.items()}
```

What your're doing is just updating the local variable `value` and not the actual value of the `key` in your dictionary.

Comment: Mine's shorter :P  You don't need the if-else, there's already a conditional filter on dict-comprehension.  (If you don't update it, then the value will be the same; so, only update the ones that change by filtering out the ones that don't.)

Comment: Ah well, you got me on the more pythonic way. :P